# ABAddresBook Permission in iOS 6 Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

Do you know if permissions are working on the simulator? I request access, but can't see my application in Pricacy settings, also I do get back an array of all the contacts, etc. And according to my code access has been already granted. Is this a simulator issue?

Answer (score 4):

The iOS6 release notes (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html)) clearly state that no privacy alerts are displayed for apps that access Photos, Contacts, Calendar, and Reminders.

You must test privacy on a real device.

Simulator limitations quoted from the iOS 6 release notes:

```
Simulator
* No privacy alerts are displayed in iOS Simulator for apps that access Photos, Contacts, Calendar, and Reminders.
* For this release, iOS Simulator does not support testing In-App Purchase. Please use a device to test your apps that use this feature.
* When attempting to play an MP3 sound in Simulator, you will hear a popping sound instead.
```

Comment: It should be noted that iOS 7 does prompt for Contacts permissions. I can't say with certainty if it prompts for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't count on the simulator. I have myself experienced issues with the simulator and in regards with asking Calendar/Addressbook permissions. To be on the safe side I would recommend that you test against a real device.